# Replace waitsFor() and runs() in Jasmine 2.0

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I kept reading about the changes in async approach in Jasmine 2.0, but i still cannot grasp the concept, so maybe someone can help me redesign the following code:

```
it("Description", () => {
        // Arrange
        spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake((params) => {
            params.success(someObject);
        });

        waitsFor(() => {
            return someList[0] != null;
        });

        // Act
        viewModel.init();

        // Assert
        runs(() => {
            expect(someList[0].id).toEqual(someObject.id);
        });
    });
```

The `viewModel.init()` method is the one that populates `someList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Artem, I came up with this solution:

```
   ajaxSpy = spyOn($, 'ajax');

   describe("Text", () => {

    function bindSpyAndPromise(JSONResult: any[]): MyViewModel {

        var d = $.Deferred();
        d.resolve(JSONResult);

        ajaxSpy.and.returnValue(d.promise());

        return new MyViewModel();
    }

    it("Text", () => {

        viewModel = bindSpyAndPromise(someObject);

        var promisse = viewModel.init();

        promisse.then(
            () => {expect(someList[0].id).toEqual(someObject.id);
            });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
it("Description", done => {
    // Arrange
    spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake((params) => {
        params.success(someObject);
    });

    // Act
    viewModel.init();

    somePromise.then(() => {
        expect(someList[0].id).toEqual(someObject.id);
        done();
    });
});
```

Quick-and-dirty replacement for waitsFor:

```
function waitsAndRuns(condition: () => boolean, timeout: number, onTimeout: () => void, onDone: () => void) {
    var timeoutHandle = setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(intervalHandle);
        onTimeout();
    }, timeout);
    var intervalHandle = setInterval(() => {
        if (condition()) {
            clearInterval(intervalHandle);
            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
            onDone();
        }
    }, 10);
}
```

Usage in spec:

```
waitsAndRuns(() => someList[0] != null, 1000, done, () => {
    expect(someList[0].id).toEqual(someObject.id);
    done();
});
```